# Backbone routes and target="_blank" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing

Does anybody know why `target="_blank"` doesn't work in Backbone app? Page opens in the same tab..

In my template:

```
<a href="/pages/{{id}}" target="_blank">Open it</a>
```

It opens in the same tab. Is there any solution for this?

Thanks

**Answer**

In your Router.js inside common click function use this conditional:

```
if ($(event.currentTarget).prop('target') === '_blank') {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like voodoo. Can you make a demo?

Comment: i'm not sure it's on my localhost

Comment: Are you using `Backbone.history`?

Comment: yep, it admited that it works like <a href="../pages/{{id}}>

Comment: and found easy solution

Comment: avoid answering in the question itself..